# Trying to make an object disappear when a statement is true~~~Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I get the feeling this is going to have a real simple solution, but seeing as how I've spent the last three days trying to get something like this to work, I turned towards this site again.
I'm trying to make a slider widget disappear after it reaches 200, and what I have I think should be working, but as is my fatal flaw with everything, it's not. I'm kinda struggling with this and I've been researching how to set something like this up, so truly, any help is welcome and greatly appreciated.

```
def oneScoop():
    if rectSlider == 200:   
        rectSlider.destroy()
oneScoopButton = Button(root,command = oneScoop, bg="light yellow", text="One Scoop")  
canvas.create_window(400, 40, width=100,height=25,anchor=NW, window=oneScoopButton)
```

Comment: What is `rectSlider`?  It seems weird to have an object with a `.destroy()` method that ever equals an `int`.

Comment: what is rectSlider? integer or object ?

Comment: If `rectSlider` is the `Scale` widget like I think it is, it seems like you would want `rectSlider.get() == 200`

Comment: @furas rectSlider is an object, and maccartm I think you may have the solution right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting my comment as a formal answer so we can mark this question as resolved:

The problem seems to be that `rectSlider` is a `Scale` object, so checking:

```
if rectSlider == 200:
```

Does not make sense. The fix is to simply use the `Scale.get()` function to check the value:

```
if rectSlider.get() == 200:
```

For anyone else having a similar problem here's a small example of how the code will work:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def done():

    if w.get() == 200:
        w.destroy()

w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL, command = lambda x: done() ) 
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Once the `Scale` widget's value reaches 200, the widget is destroyed.